# How to fix "EnableInput can only be specified on a Pawn for its Controller" error in output log

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I'm creating a weapon system for my third person shooter project and I'm having some problems getting input to the gun.

With the way I have set up my classes, I have ACharacter parented player classes and APawn parented weapon classes. Right now, I'm trying to set up some key binds (fire, alt-fire, reload) to the weapon that the player is holding, but I'm getting an error. I think my code is almost there, I'm just having problems with which controller I need to be getting input from.

My player class is just a basic third-person character class. I couldn't create an instance of the weapon as a component in the player class, so I used SpawnActor<>() and just attached the weapon instance to the player instance when the game starts. I have created a parent class called ALTWeapon that parents all my weapon classes and I have a subclass variable called PlayerWeaponAtSpawnClass that holds the ALTWeapon child class that I want to spawn on the player. I'm including my code for the player here and I've omitted some code that doesn't need to be included in this post.

```
// Called when the game starts or when spawned
void ALTPlayer::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();

    UWorld* World = GetWorld();
    if (World && PlayerWeaponAtSpawnClass != NULL)
    {
        // Creating default weapon
        FAttachmentTransformRules* TransformRule;
        ALTWeapon* Weapon = World->SpawnActor<ALTWeapon>(PlayerWeaponAtSpawnClass);
        Weapon->AttachToComponent(GetMesh(), TransformRule->KeepRelativeTransform);

        // Setting current held weapon
        CurrentWeaponClass = PlayerWeaponAtSpawnClass;
    }
}
```

Moving into the code file for the spawned weapon, I have bound the fire and reload input events just like in the player class. I'll include that code here.

```
void ALaserGun::SetupPlayerInputComponent(UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent)
{
    Super::SetupPlayerInputComponent(PlayerInputComponent);

    // Binding input events
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAction("Fire", IE_Pressed, this, &ALaserGun::OnFire);
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAction("Reload", IE_Pressed, this, &ALaserGun::OnReload);
}

void ALaserGun::OnFire()
{
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Gun fired"));
}

void ALaserGun::OnReload()
{
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Gun reloaded"));
}
```

Now, when I compile and then hit play, I get this error message in the output log for Unreal.

> LogPawn: Error: EnableInput can only be specified on a Pawn for its Controller

From my own research, I've tried to get the controller of the player holding the gun through casting and such but I didn't have any luck there. I looked into the definition of the EnableInput function and found some useful info, but I don't know what to do with it. I'll include the function definition here.

```
void APawn::EnableInput(class APlayerController* PlayerController)
{
    if (PlayerController == Controller || PlayerController == nullptr)
    {
        bInputEnabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        UE_LOG(LogPawn, Error, TEXT("EnableInput can only be specified on a Pawn for its Controller"));
    }
}
```

If anyone has some insight on how to fix this, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It just happened to me. I fixed it this way:

In your **PlayerController** class:

```
AMyPlayerController::AMyPlayerController()
{
    AutoReceiveInput = EAutoReceiveInput::Player0;
}
```

In your **Character** class:

```
AMyThirdPersonCharacter::AMyThirdPersonCharacter()
{
    AutoPossessPlayer = EAutoReceiveInput::Player0;
}
```

> I have ACharacter parented player classes and APawn parented weapon classes.

I may be wrong but I believe your Weapon class should inherit from AActor instead of APawn because it will be already controlled by ACharacter ( ACharacter inherit from APawn ).